# How can I use a value from one column in another, inside a Datatables constructor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, datatable

I have a constructor, in Typescript, where a datatable is constructed, with values like 'orderable', 'data' and 'name'. My question is:

How can I set the visibility of one column, based on the value of another, in the same row?
I tried with the 'render', which made it possible for me to edit the text. So if I edit the text, the best I can do is set it to an empty string(''), which is not what I want. What I want is to hide the column in that row, something achievable through 'visible: false', for example.
Below is my example, with already existing code in the constructor:

```
data: 'ColumnData',
name: 'ColumnName',
orderable: false,
visibility: /*insert logic here*/,
render: (data: any, t: string, row: any, meta: DataTables.CellMetaSettings) => {
    switch (row['ColumnThatThisOneDependsOn']) {
        case 1:
            return ``;
        default:
            return `<div>${data}</div>`;
    }
}
```

What I wish I could do would be to change the visibility of column 'ColumnName'(to 'true' or 'false'), depending on the value of column 'ColumnThisOneDependsOn'.
Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: The option name is `visible` and it sets the visibility of the *entire* column. Perhaps you want to set the *cell* content using the contents of another cell?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! That's right, the settings name is 'visible', but I'm afraid I don't want only for 1 cell. Rather I want for the entire column.

Comment: A column can either be visible or not visible. If it is not visible then *all* column cells (from all rows) are not visible. In this context your requirement  *...hide the column in that row* makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work, after hours of grueling wallbashing! Instead of editing the settings in the typescript constructor(which was what I was trying to do), I just created a .js function in the cshtml, and I set that function to be used on the datatable .init and .draw methods!